# Remove key from map based on predicate clojure

Tags: clojure

Say I have a map `m` like `{"good1" 1, "bad1" 1, "good2" 2, "bad2" 2}`, and I'd like to remove entries based on some predicate over the keys of the map, one way to do this would be:

```
(defn dissoc-by [f m] (->> m (filter (complement f)) (into {})))
(dissoc-by #(.contains (first %1) "bad") m)
 => {"good1" 1, "good2" 2}
```

Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this in clojure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very normal way of going about it, with the one correction that a sequence from a map is a sequence of pairs [key value] rather than just the keys, so your filter function needs to use the key explicitly

```
user> (defn dissoc-by [f m] (->> m (filter #(f (first %))) (into {})))
#'user/dissoc-by
user> (dissoc-by #(.contains % "good") m)
{"good1" 1, "good2" 2}
```

If you would like to get fancy about it and [use a transducer](https://clojure.org/reference/transducers) this function can be made more efficient by eliminating the intermediate sequences that are allocated to move data from one step to the next.

```
user> (defn dissoc-by [f m]
        (into {} (filter #(f (first %))) m))
#'user/dissoc-by
user> (dissoc-by #(.contains % "good") m)
{"good1" 1, "good2" 2}
```

`into` takes an optional middle argument, a transducer function, that can filter or transform the data as it is pored into the collection.

Comment: Good catch! I just noticed that as well, but decided perhaps a more general solution would be to just pass the key-value pair to the predicate instead. I also realized that the naming convention of the function implies the predicate should remove, not keep elements.

Comment: yep, thats in the question that way as well. [sic]

Comment: choose to match the input or output eh?

Comment: The problem with using `into` here is that `dissoc-by` constructs a completely new structure every time it's called.  Even if you don't actually remove anything, the entire map structure is copied, which is wasteful.  This is in constrast to Thumbnail's answer, which (by `dissoc`ing only those keys to be removed) allows the new map to share structure with the original map.  Depending your application, this can make a huge impact on memory use.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the keys will be the same objects and the values will be the same objects. These are the parts with the greatest potential to be large. the map structure it's self is bounded in size so there is a limit on how large it can be. As this code approaches that limit generating the intermediate list of items to remove will grow large so it's difficult to say in general what is better for exceptional circumstances. 
keep in mind that there is a limited amount of possible internal structure in clojure maps.

Answer (score 7):

Given

```
(def data {"good1" 1, "bad1" 1, "good2" 2, "bad2" 2})
```

define

```
(defn remove-keys [pred m]
  (apply dissoc m (filter pred (keys m))))
```

then

```
(remove-keys #(string/includes? % "bad") data)
=> {"good1" 1, "good2" 2}
```

Similar functions are defined in/at [*The Clojure Cookbook*](https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/02_composite-data/2-21_applying-functions-to.asciidoc#sec_composite_maps_as_seqs).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that does exactly what you need:

```
(def data {"good1" 1, "bad1" 1, "good2" 2, "bad2" 2})

(into (empty data) 
      (filter (fn [[k v]] (clojure.string/includes? k "good")) 
              data))

{"good1" 1, "good2" 2}
```